# Network printer recognized but not printing

Tags: printing, canon, adobe-reader

On my Ubuntu machine, a network printer on LAN is recognized (by just selecting `Network` on `Add a New Printer` menu). Applications recognize it too. However the info shown on the printer panel ("System settings" --> "Printer") does not seem what Ubuntu obtains from the printer; it's IP address is `localhost`, clicking "Jobs"-->"Show" always shows empty job list, and clicking "Print Test Page" doesn't do anything.

Probably because of that, I get an error when I try to print a pdf from `Acrobat Reader`.

```
lpr: unsupported document-format application/vnd.adobe-reader-postscript
```

Ubuntu `Quantal`, acroread v9.5.5, Canon MG6330

With the same file, I can print without any problem from Mac OSX 10.8.4. Is there any workaround? And if let me know also if any information is needed. Thank you!

---

Update 6/14/2013) Thanks for the comments and answer. I managed to be able to print from Ubuntu. With @quidage's answer, I was able to "operate" printer; `Print Test Page` sends "something" to the printer so that it beeps but without printing anything, and the admin web page on Ubuntu says the job is completed. Then I'm ashamed to say that I had to install driver...from [this web site](http://cweb.canon.jp/cgi-bin/download/select-product-by-catg.cgi?i_cd_pr_catg=011) to select the printer I have.

Comment: It may be prudent to check if you have all the latest updates with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: @SimplySimon I do `apt-get update` and then `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-update` almost everyday. Do you have particular components in mind to upgate?

Comment: Can you confirm whether this is a new problem your facing with this printer (ie, did it work for you in the past and suddenly stopped working)? Also, because canon printer drivers are a hassle to set up in Linux, can you please confirm how you installed them?

Comment: Have you by chance enabled a firewall recently? You might have blocked a udp port or something. If you **have** enabled a firewall, try disabling it and see if you can print.

Comment: @Marc I believe there's no FW in my LAN/home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try to configure the printer new using cups, type

`http://localhost:631/`

into any browser, remove the printer from printers list and add it again in the webinterface by entering the ip. There you can choose the driver for the printer by yourself. If it is a network print, the address cannot be localhost, this is your computer.

Give feedback if you have any questions