# Network printing issue on HP LaserJet 4250 from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, printing, laserjet

I am trying to set up an HP LaserJet 4250 on my private LAN (link 192.168.1.0/24).

I can `ping` it on that link. I can also detect it using `nmap` and correctly detect its MAC HW address using `arp`.

```
$ sudo nmap -Pn 192.168.1.0/24
...
$ arp -n 192.168.1.37   # where the IP is the DHCP provided  printer's IP.
...
```

I have also arranged for my router and its DHCP to stick to that private IP  address. (I made `192.168.1.37` a static address on the link.)

***Problem:***
After setting up the LJ4250 printer in CUPS 1.7.2 (at `http://localhost:631/admin`) with either the Postscript driver or the ppd configuration file (downloaded from HP pages), it  does not respond at all when I throw either a print job or a test page at it over the network. I tried from GUI and from CLI with: 
`$ lpr -P _printer-name_`.
The error message is: *"Unable to write print data: Broken pipe."*

I have seen other reports pn network printing issues on various forums (including [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307821/network-printer-recognized-but-not-printing) on AU), but I am at my wit's end after more than 12 hours poking at it.

I think I need help. How should I go about solving this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The printer had been used in another network previously, where MAC HW address based network authentication mechanism was set up.

Conducting a cold reset on the printer wiped whatever was left of its previous config and solved the problem. That printer is now accessible from Mac, Win and Lx clients on its link with no HW-authentication.

The pbm is solved, although I could not get to the bottom of how in-printer-memory string values left over from a previous configuration could thwart current network printing.